# How to get selectedItem from comboBox itemrenderer in datagrid and display value in another column

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, flex4.5, itemrenderer

I am having an issue with itemRender in a datagrid. Actually I have a dataProvider which populates 2 columns in my datagrid. The first column data is rendered in a TextInput and the second column data is rendered in a comboBox. What I want now is that when I selected an element from the comboBox of a row in the grid. I want to show the selectedItem value in the corresponding TextInput on the same row of the first column.

I want to know if there is any datagrid property that can help me do this? Or if someone can guide me what to code in the change handler of the comboBox? See my codes below.

I need help. Pls sort this out for me someone.

```
    <mx:DataGrid id="myDG" rowHeight="25" dataProvider="{my_arrayColl}" width="100%" height="205" chromeColor="#D0CCAF" headerHeight="0" showHeaders="false">
                    <mx:columns>
                        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="My Header 1"                                                                        
                                           editable="true"                                                                        
                                           dataField="LBL"                                                                            
                                           >
                            <mx:itemRenderer>
                                <fx:Component>
                                    <mx:HBox horizontalAlign="left" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off">


                                        <fx:Script>
                                            <![CDATA[
                                                import mx.controls.Alert;
                                                import mx.controls.Text;

                                                import spark.events.TextOperationEvent;

                                                protected function label_txt_changeHandler(event:TextOperationEvent):void
                                                {
                                                    data.LBL = label_txt.text;
                                                }   


                                            ]]>
                                        </fx:Script>

                                        <s:TextInput id="label_txt" change="label_txt_changeHandler(event)" text="{data.LBL}" width="98%"/>
                                    </mx:HBox>
                                </fx:Component>
                            </mx:itemRenderer>
                        </mx:DataGridColumn>    

                        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="My Header 2"                                                                       
                                           editable="true"                                                                                
                                           rendererIsEditor="true"                                                                        
                                           dataField="ALIAS"                                                                            
                                           >
                            <mx:itemRenderer>
                                <fx:Component>
                                        <mx:ComboBox height="80%" change="mycb_changeHandler(event)" labelField="ALIAS" dataProvider="{outerDocument.mycb_array}">
                                            <fx:Script>
                                                <![CDATA[
                                                    import mx.events.ListEvent;

                                                    protected function mycb_changeHandler(event:ListEvent):void
                                                    {

                                                    }

                                                ]]>
                                            </fx:Script>

                                        </mx:ComboBox>
                                </fx:Component>
                            </mx:itemRenderer>
                        </mx:DataGridColumn>

                    </mx:columns>
                </mx:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you want to update the dataprovider of DataGrid, based on selection in your ComboBox component in itemRenderer. You can do that by going to the owner object and updating the respective object in data. Just keep itemRenderer in a separate mxml and put your debug pointer in label_txt_changeHandler method.

Hope it helps..